# Не могу подключить ключ api гугл карт

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, карты

Добрый день. Не получается подключить ключ api карт. Когда подключаю, то вместо карты белый экран. Вот ключ: AIzaSyD7MfENFAieab3agrQpIc3cbEPIhsQkFLc. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Simple markers</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.407469, 32.049478);
  var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.984451, 36.242074);
  var pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.475931, 35.023183);
  var pos3 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.453168, 30.730843);
  var pos4 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.862328, 24.044550);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos1,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Гимназическая набережная, 16. +38 (057) 752-04-08',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }

  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos2,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Фрунзе, 6, оф.107. +38 (068) 195-50-04.',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos3,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Транспортная, 3. +38 (067) 218-41-74.',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos4,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Промышленная, 50/52. +38 (067) 402-48-49.',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
</style>
```

Comment: Разметку в порядок приведите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить &key=... в строку запуска скрипта maps.googleapis.com/maps/api

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Simple markers</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyD7MfENFAieab3agrQpIc3cbEPIhsQkFLc"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.407469, 32.049478);
  var pos1 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.984451, 36.242074);
  var pos2 = new google.maps.LatLng(48.475931, 35.023183);
  var pos3 = new google.maps.LatLng(46.453168, 30.730843);
  var pos4 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.862328, 24.044550);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos1,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Гимназическая набережная, 16. +38 (057) 752-04-08',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }

  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos2,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Фрунзе, 6, оф.107. +38 (068) 195-50-04.',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos3,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Транспортная, 3. +38 (067) 218-41-74.',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos4,
    map: map,
    title: 'ул. Промышленная, 50/52. +38 (067) 402-48-49.',
    icon: {
      url: "https://prisma-group.com.ua/wp-content/themes/write365/classic/img/maps.png",
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(47, 57)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
</style>
```